# MySQL count values up until specific row

Tags: php, mysql

Apologies if I'm not explaining my situation in perfect detail as I'm not a native speaker. I'm sure this is fairly simple for most people, but I struggle with it. I'm using php/mysql.

Suppose I have a database as follows:

```
id   game   scorer
1     1      molly
2     1      sarah
3     1      angela
4     1      molly
5     2      jane
6     2      molly
7     2      sarah
```

How would I write a query to present the scorers for each game with the number of goals they have scored during the season up until that particular goal?

```
Example: 
Game 1: Molly (1st), Sarah (1st), Angela (1st), Molly (2nd)
Game 2: Jane (1st), Molly (3rd), Sarah (2nd)
```

Comment: how is the sorting done (who goes first)? why is molly present twice on game 1?

Comment: where is the goals they scored...?

Comment: Wow, you guys are fast.

1. Sorting in the db is based on who scores first. So for game 1, Molly scored goals 1 & 4, Sarah got the second goal and Angela the third. That's why Molly appears twice for that game.

2. Each entry in the database represents one goal.

Comment: So, just to check, you actually want the result to look as per the example?

Comment: Yes. Or instead of such a comma separated format on one row it would be fine to have each entry/goal on a separate line as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE goals
(goal_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,game INT NOT NULL
,scorer VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO goals VALUES
(1,1,'molly'),
(2,1,'sarah'),
(3,1,'angela'),
(4,1,'molly'),
(5,2,'jane'),
(6,2,'molly'),
(7,2,'sarah');


SELECT game, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(scorer,'(',rank,')')) scorers FROM 
(
SELECT x.game
     , x.scorer
     , COUNT(*) rank 
  FROM goals x 
  JOIN goals y 
    ON y.scorer = x.scorer 
   AND y.goal_id <= x.goal_id 
 GROUP 
    BY x.game,x.goal_id,x.scorer
)n
GROUP BY game;

+------+--------------------------------------+
| game | scorers                              |
+------+--------------------------------------+
|    1 | molly(1),sarah(1),angela(1),molly(2) |
|    2 | jane(1),molly(3),sarah(2)            |
+------+--------------------------------------+
```

The subquery on its own will give the alternative display

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

```
<?php
$query="SELECT * FROM `goals`";
$result =   mysqli_query($query);
$goals_scored   =   array();
$scorer_goals   =   array();
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){    
    $score  =   array('scorer'=>$row['scorer']);    
    if(isset($scorer_goals[$row['scorer']])){       
        $scorer_goals[$row['scorer']]++;
        $score['goal_number']=$scorer_goals[$row['scorer']];
        array_push($goals_scored[$row['game']], $score);
    }
    else{       
        $scorer_goals[$row['scorer']]   =   1;
        $score['goal_number']=$scorer_goals[$row['scorer']];
        $goals_scored[$row['game']] =   array($score);
    }   
}
echo '<table>';
foreach($goals_scored as $key=>$goals){ 
    echo '<tr><td>Game '.$key.'</td>';
    foreach($goals as $goal){
        echo '<td>'.$goal['scorer'].'( '.$goal['goal_number'].' )</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
?>
```

Comment: Thanks. Tried it but got a couple of error messages.  

Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given on row 3  
Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given on row 6

Comment: Before this you need to connect to the mySql db